# marshaling java objects instantiated from classes which implement interfaces with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, interface, jaxb

How can we marshal objects into XML files using JAXB when we use interfaces for our classes? I have the following simple classes:

```
public interface IBook {

    public abstract String getName();

    public abstract void setName(String name);

}
@XmlRootElement
public class Book implements IBook {

    private String name;

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name ="BookTitle")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
public class BookStore {

    @XmlElement(name ="BookStoreName")
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name ="bookList")
    @XmlAnyElement
    public HashSet<IBook> books= new HashSet<IBook>();

    }
```

and when I try to marshal an object from BookStore into an XML file, I get the following error:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: Weder class de.uni_paderborn.books.Book noch eine der zugehörigen Superklassen ist diesem Kontext bekannt.
```

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Weder class de.uni_paderborn.books.Book noch eine der zugehörigen Superklassen ist diesem Kontext bekannt.]

Sorry for the German error message, but my OS is German. This means that neither the class Book nor one of its superclasses is known in this context! Why do I get such an error?

Comment: You may find the following useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html.  Also, I'm curious why you are using `@XmlAnyElement` on the `books` field.

Comment: Because without it I get another error that tells I am trying to marshal an interface, since the elements in books `HashSet` are from `IBook`, and not from `Book`. Thanks!

Comment: I have added an answer that should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27319803/383861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to map a field/property that is an interface type you use the `type` setting on the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name ="bookList")
@XmlElement(type=Book.class, name="book")
public HashSet<IBook> books= new HashSet<IBook>();
```

Comment: OK, thanks! it is similar to the previous answer, but again, should I mention each and every class that may go into my `HashSet<IBook> books`?

Comment: @Anas You have different impls that can go in?

Comment: Yes, they can be from different impls

Comment: actually, I just found out that this solution is better than the other since in the unmarshalling process I get the objects from the exact required classes. But the question remains, what about the situation in which I have multiple possible implementations of my interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are missing [@XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) in your BookStore class. Add it to your BookStore class like this

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Book.class})
public class BookStore {

    @XmlElement(name = "BookStoreName")
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bookList")
    @XmlAnyElement
    public HashSet<IBook> books = new HashSet<IBook>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        BookStore bookStore = new BookStore();
        bookStore.name = "FooBookStore";
        Book e = new Book();
        e.setName("Java");
        bookStore.books.add(e);

        /**
         * Create JAXB Context from the classes to be serialized
         */
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookStore.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(bookStore, System.out);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bookStore>
    <BookStoreName>FooBookStore</BookStoreName>
    <bookList>
        <book>
            <BookTitle>Java</BookTitle>
        </book>
    </bookList>
</bookStore>
```

Comment: should I add this `@XmlSeeAlso`for each class type that I might use in the list of books? Thanks!

Comment: Yes , if they are different impls

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem for the same exception.
I had 2 Different BookStore classes where only packages differ:
hello.number.one.BookStore
hello.number.two.BookStore

My error was I was filling XML set with package ..one.. But included the BookStore class with package ..two.. because eclipse included it like that for me (automatically), and so did not notice the wrong BookStore class. 
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookStore.class);

it is simple but long searching indeed...hope it helps somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem while working with spring resp. adding a `Jaxb2Marshaller` bean.
i had the same error message because of not setting the

`marshaller.setPackagesToScan(...)`

properly with the right package names of the generated files, wich resulted in the same exception.

```
@Bean(name = "someMarshaller"
Jaxb2Marshaller someMarshaller() {
    final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("my.package.one", "my.package.two");
    return marshaller;
}
```